# trouble with Python package import command in Spyder5

Tags: python, math, anaconda, robotics

having the need to use a package not included in the Anaconda repository (https://github.com/NxRLab/ModernRobotics), I followed the instructions in the official Anaconda documentation and installed, running the Anaconda command terminal as administrator, pip and then followed the package of interest with the instruction *pip install modern-robotics*, receiving the positive result of the installation as feedback.
Afterwards I checked the presence of the package with *conda list* and then, for greater security, from Anaconda Navigator Environment, seeing it regularly installed.

Now, in a python script in Spider5, I entered *import modern-robotics as mr*, but I get the red error incorrect syntax.

> Invalid sintax pyfLakes E

From the Code Analyzer report in Spyder IDE, I've

> ************** Module robotics_test*
> *E0001:syntax-error: 11,14: Parsing failed: 'invalid syntax (<unknown>, line 11)'*

But the package is there !
Having suspected that there might be inconsistencies in the updating of the packages as seen by Spider IDE, I closed the entire environment (including Anaconda Navigator) and restarted it, but the problem remains. Needless to say, I also trivially turned the PC off and on again.

I am not a guru of Python or other languages, I use them for scientific needs, but now I don't understand the origin of the error.